# Unable to load the image picker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

I want to load the image picker and **hide the drop down select and only display images**

I have tried with below code based on https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/image-picker/image-picker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js">


</script>
</head>


<body>

                <select multiple="multiple" id="image-picker-select" class="image-picker show-html">
                  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
                  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
                  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
                  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
                </select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
    $("select").imagepicker({
hide_select: true
})
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited and want to hide the drop down select

Answer (score -1):

The first issue is that you are getting a CORB blocking error due to your leeching of the raw.github domain for the imagepicker library.
So download the file into your project. To hide the selector you can simple initialize using:

```
$("select").imagepicker({
    hide_select: true
});
```

Comment: Corse was already solved at the time you posted the answer. But this isnt working anymore, For a material select you need to do something else.

Comment: The images never gets selected when materialize is used